# Flutter Firebase Database not working on release after publish in Google play

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play

Flutter Firebase Database not working on release after publish in Google play
and Firebase Auth working fine .
I have added the SHA from Google play console to firebase console

I have no problems when running on debug mode

Comment: Go to google play store app > App integrity > App signing. Have you already added these SHA1 and SHA256 to your firebase app?

Comment: also please make sure, that you have given internet access in the AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Did you modify firebase rules?

Comment: thanks it was firebase rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by modify firebase rules works fine to me

thanks Kashif Ali Bhatti for the answer in command above.

Comment: What rules (and how) did you modify?

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the SHA1 signature key generated by the google console after publishing your app.
Follow these steps:

1. Go to play console
2. Scroll down to the Configuration setting
3. Copy the sha1 or sha256 signature
4. open firebase your console
5. go to project settings and select the android app.
6. paste the sha signature.

Hope it works for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you publish your `apk` to the `PlayStore`, you get assigned with a singing certificate `SHA1`. That you have to add to your firebase console.

Get `SHA Certificate` from `playstore` and add it to the `firebase` console

[image]

Comment: yes I already added the SHA, but not work